# Creating user friendly URL with directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

I have a page where the user signs up and they're redirected to their profile. Their profile URL is: example.com/profiles/?username=sam, where sam can be any name. This works successfully, but i'm trying to make the URL cleaner. I want to make the URL look like this: example.com/profiles/sam Here's my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /profiles/?\?username=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /profiles/%1? [L,R]
RewriteRule ^(?:profiles/)?([0-9]+)/?$ /profiles/?username=$1 [L]

    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
        BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

        # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
        BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

        # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
        # BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

        # NOTE: Due to a bug in mod_setenvif up to Apache 2.0.48
        # the above regex won't work. You can use the following
        # workaround to get the desired effect:
        BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

        # Don't compress images
        SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI .(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
        Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

profiles in example.com/profiles/ is a directory. Inside profiles is an index.php file, this is the PHP file that creates the dynamic page. My .htaccess file is located in the root folder. I am also using GoDaddy. GoDaddy states that: "Because enabling mod_rewrite is handled at a global level, you do not need to enable it in your httpd.conf file. You only need to add the desired code to the body of your .htaccess file. The .htaccess file containing the rewrite rules must be in the same directory as the target files."

With my .htaccess like that, it changes the URL from example.com/profiles/?username=sam to example.com/profiles/sam but the profile is not shown at all, instead a 404 error page is shown, meaning the page does not exist. The page should exist. Also, adding Options +Multiviews produces the same 404 error. Also with Options +Multiviews, some pages display the CSS instead of the PHP page.

How can I make it so that example.com/profiles/?username=sam is redirected to example.com/profiles/sam and make the profile page actually show up?

Comment: `[R]` means a client-side redirect, which means you're rewriting and then redirecting the client to the new url. you don't have a "physical" /profiles/johndoe.php" page on your server, so you end up producing a 404. the urls the client sees in their browser should ALWAYS be the friendly ones, and then your rewrites translate those friendly/public urls into the "ugly" internal ones. you rewrites are going the other direction.

Comment: @MarcB This makes a lot of sense, but how do I accomplish this? How do I show the client the user friendly URL, but internally I translate the friendly ones into the ugly ones?

Comment: you always send out html like `<a href="/profiles/johndoe.php">`, and then your rewrite converts that to the internal `/foo/bar/profile.php?johndoe.php`. that rewrite stays purely internal, and that internal-only/ugly url is never visible to the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your rules like this in `/profile/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /profiles/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /\?username=([^&\s]+) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ %1? [L,R=302] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
```

- Your rule was only matching `[0-9]+` after `/profile/`, which won't match `sam`.
- For adding `.php` you should check it's existence first.

Comment: Hmm, this is still displaying the 404 page and not the profile. It's thinking that example.com/profiles/sam is an actual file, but it's really a dynamic link from example.com/profiles/?username=sam

Comment: When I do example.com/profiles/index/sam it is throwing a 500 internal server error

Comment: profiles in example.com/profiles/ is a directory, the only part of my site that has .htaccess is the root folder. I figured since the .htaccess is in the root, then it will affect the site on a global scale

Comment: @MarcB provided an interesting comment, please take a look at it up in my question

Comment: Also, example.com/profiles/sam is working, but it's redirecting to a 404 error. How can I make it so that the client sees this friendly URL, but internally it's the ugly URL?

Comment: If I enter example.com/profiles/?username=sam it redirects successfully to example.com/profiles/sam but the profile is not displaying, instead a 404 error is shown as if the page does not exist

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115918/discussion-between-anubhava-and-user2896120).